# CSV file writing with a blank line between every line

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a loop that attempts to append data from a dictionary to the end of a CSV file each time through the loop.

As part of that, I'd like to be able to check if it's sheet is blank, has been cleared or is empty and if true, then output the header and the row. Otherwise, I dont want the header to print again, only the row.

In trying to find a way to check that the first row is my header or blank, I tried 2 approaches:

1. I read the csv, converted every row to a `list` and checked to see if the first entry was blank. With the newline parameter on, it would start printing on line 2 so checking if the first element of the list was blank returned true everytime. If i tried to check the 2nd element, i would get index out of range error on my first run.
2. I used `csv.Sniffer()`'s `has_header` to check if the file had a header.

Similar error here because i had `newline=''` in the `open()` statement. Because of that, for some reason it would always output the first entry on line 2 and the `has_header` always returned false even if the file did already have a header.

I was finally able to get the `has_header()` to work correctly by removing the `newline=''` parameter from the `open()` but now it's putting a blank space between every output.

How can I simply remove these lines from my output while still being able to check my condition? Any help is appreciated!

this is my code:

```
    with open(filename+'.csv', "r") as f_read, open(filename+'.csv', "a") as f_append:

        def is_empty(*, csv_file_obj):
            try:
                return csv.Sniffer().has_header(f_read.read())

            except csv.Error:
                print('ran except')
                return False

        writer = csv.DictWriter(f_append, dict.keys())
        if is_empty(csv_file_obj=f_read):
            print('returned true')

            writer.writerow(dict)
        else:
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow(dict)
```

What the CSV should look like without the blank lines between every row.

[image: what the CSV should look like without the blank lines]

Comment: `newline=''` is required when you write a file or you get the infamous blank lines

Comment: problem is that `csv.Sniffer().has_header(f_read.read())` reads the file, but you're not rewinding it, so it's fully consumed

Comment: yea but like i said, this causes all output to begin on line 2 making it difficult to check if i have a header or if the file is entirely blank. what do you mean by "you're not rewinding it"

Comment: wait: don't use the same file for reading & appending. Use another file to write into (plus this is not portable)

Comment: Im getting my data from a dictionary that's generated every time through the loop. How would using 2 files solve my issue?